# Do you use "to" after travel in this question?

Tags: prepositions, questions

Which of these questions sound more natural?

1. Where are you going to travel?

Or

2. Where are you going to travel to?

I think number 2 is right. Even though "Where are you going" seems to be more common than "Where are you going to"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both could be correct, depending on what you mean by 'travel'.

*To travel* can mean to journey from one place to another, and when we use it like this it is common to include where we are going *to*.

But *travel* can also mean an extended period of traveling punctuated by stopovers, eg "*I'm going travelling in Europe*". You can also speak about traveling *around* a place, eg "*I spent the summer traveling around Europe*". Your first example could be a normal response to someone declaring "*I'm going traveling*", but your second option is more appropriate if someone is going on a specific journey from one place to another.